# Clojure print with values the same line as keys

Tags: clojure, formatting

How can I pretty print a nested data structure such that:

- The value always begins on the same line as the key.
- Keys are always on a newline.

At the moment, I get this:

```
(clojure.pprint/pprint {:id1 "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                        :id2 "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"}))
```

Prints the values "aaa..." and "bbb..." on newlines.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [zprint](https://github.com/kkinnear/zprint), which tries very hard to keep the values on the same lines as the keys.  If a value doesn't fit on the same line as the key (that is, within the current "width"), it will put the value (indented by default) on the next line.  You can change the line width and also change whether or not it indents things it puts on the next line when it has to do so.

zprint has a number of additional features to print maps (particularly at the REPL) more useably.  It will sort the keys and you can specify certain keys to be output first.  You can color certain keys differently from other keys.  It has a bunch of capabilities that are designed to allow a person to get more information from a Clojure map with less effort.

Comment: Thanks. I got good results with `(zprint.core/zprint data 1000 {:map {:force-nl? true}})`

Answer (score -1):

You can set `clojure.pprint/*print-right-margin*` to a big number so it would respect your longest value.

```
(binding [clojure.pprint/*print-right-margin* 100]
  (clojure.pprint/pprint {:id1 "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                          :id2 "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"}))
#=> {:id1 "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
     :id2 "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"}
```

or do some dirty move and set this var globally

```
(alter-var-root #'clojure.pprint/*print-right-margin* (constantly 100))
(clojure.pprint/pprint {:id1 "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                        :id2 "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"})
#=> {:id1 "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
     :id2 "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"}
```

Comment: This will not produce a newline before the key, but will result in multiple keypairs on the same line.